# Firefox Account - Export user data (GDPR)

Tags: privacy, firefox, gdpr

Is there a way of exporting all user data associated with a [Firefox Account](https://accounts.firefox.com/)?

1. **Yes?** where can I request/download it?
2. **No?** isn't [right of access](https://gdpr-info.eu/issues/right-of-access/) a [legal](https://gdpr-info.eu/) requirement under
       the current [GDPR legislation](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/PDF/?uri=CELEX:32016R0679)?

---

Examples of what I'm asking :

1. [Google: Download your data](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3024190?hl=en)
2. [Facebook: Accessing & Downloading Your Information](https://www.facebook.com/help/1701730696756992?helpref=hc_global_nav)
3. [GitHub: Download all of your data](https://github.blog/2018-12-19-download-your-data/)
4. [LinkedIn - Accessing Your Account Data](https://www.linkedin.com/psettings/member-data)
5. [Twitter - Your Twitter data](https://twitter.com/settings/your_twitter_data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - Right of access is a requirement under GDPR for EU residents, although it is not always implemented in the same way.

I would start with [Mozilla's Privacy Policy](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/privacy/) which has a link to a form for Data Subject Access Requests at the end - that in turn has an option for Information Requests.

It also has a link to [Information for EU, EEA, and Swiss users](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/information-eu-eea-and-swiss-users) but that page doesn't seem to specifically address your question.

Comment: Thank you for the link, [form sent](https://app.onetrust.com/app/#/webform/4ba08202-2ede-4934-a89e-f0b0870f95f0). I find amazing that Mozilla, an organization that uses privacy as their motto, doesn't implement an easy way of exporting user data.